# How does WCF provide more security than ASMX web services?

Tags: wcf, asmx, wcf-security

I am newbie to WCF, and I'd like to know how WCF provides more security over ASMX web services?

And which binding we prefer when we consider security part?

How do I choose the best binding as there are that many ?

Many thanks..

Comment: See [choosing the right WCF binding](http://weblogs.asp.net/spano/archive/2007/10/02/choosing-the-right-wcf-binding.aspx) for a quick decision flow chart (from Juval Lowy's excellent "Programming WCF Services" book)

Comment: Also: WCF **is** web services .... so your question kinda doesn't really make sense. Do you mean what additional security features does WCF offers over *legacy ASMX webservice* technology in .NET 1.1/2.0 ??

Answer (score 1):

That's a **very very broad** question.

WCF provides a lot more security by providing a lot more capabilities and options out of the box:  it supports not only transport security (using SSL and https to secure your link, like ASMX) but also supports message encryption, and messages are by default encrypted and digitally signed.

This topic [Bindings and Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731172.aspx) on MSDN might be a good starting point - it explains the various security-related features of each binding. The topic [Programming WCF Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731925.aspx) goes into more details, and the ultimate "one-stop site" for WCF security is the [WCF Security Guidance site on Codeplex](http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/) created and maintained by the Patterns & Practices group at Microsoft.

---

As for choosing the right binding - I would recommend the [decision flowchart](http://weblogs.asp.net/spano/archive/2007/10/02/choosing-the-right-wcf-binding.aspx) that Juval Lowy presents in his excellent book [Programming WCF Services](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596805489) (for intermediate to advanced developers).

Answer (score 0):

Truly, its very open question. It totally depends what are your requirements and then you can decide to choose right binding which provides security as well.

For example, you should go for basicHttpBinding or wsHttpBinding, if interoperability is your concern and you need to communicate with non-WCF systems. In some case, your service can reside on a single system, In such scenario netNamedPipeBinding will be the most efficient option.
netTcpBinding or netPeerTcpBinding might be best options, if you need to communicate across multiple computers.And if the service needs support for disconnected or queued calls, netMsmqBinding or msmqIntegrationBinding will be the candidate options.

WCF Security FAQs
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36732/WCF-FAQ-Part-3-10-security-related-FAQ

Binding Default Security
http://www.topwcftutorials.net/2012/06/wcf-bindings-default-security.html